# Write the result of expression to a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a question. I want to write the result of the expression such as y=2cos(n.Pi/3) for 100 values n into a list. Could you tell me which code I should use?

Comment: The examples section of [`Table`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) may give you some ideas.

Comment: Thanks so much :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @LouisB comments, using `Table`:

```
f[n_] := 2 Cos[n π/3]
Table[f[n], {n, 1, 100}]

(*{1, -1, -2, -1, 1, 2, 1, -1, -2, -1, 1, 2, 1, -1, -2, -1, 1, 2, 1, 
  -1, -2, -1, 1, 2, 1, -1, -2, -1, 1, 2, 1, -1, -2, -1, 1, 2, 1, -1,   
  -2, -1, 1, 2, 1, -1, -2, -1, 1, 2, 1, -1, -2, -1, 1, 2, 1, -1, -2,   
  -1, 1, 2, 1, -1, -2, -1, 1, 2, 1, -1, -2, -1, 1, 2, 1, -1, -2, -1, 1, 
   2, 1, -1, -2, -1, 1, 2, 1, -1, -2, -1, 1, 2, 1, -1, -2, -1, 1, 2, 1,-1, -2, -1}*)
```

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/269646/table-mix-with-if-function
Could you explain to me this question?

Answer (score 5):

You can take advantage of the `Listable` attribute of the trigonometric functions (ie the fact that they automatically thread over lists, to produce a list of results) as follows:

```
2 Cos[Pi/3 Range@100]
```

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/269646/table-mix-with-if-function
Could you explain to me this question?

Answer (score 1):

Using `Array` :

```
Array[2 Cos[# \[Pi]/3] &, 100]
```

also delivers the same output. If you don't want to use pure functions or if a function is available, then you can use the function (as given in the other answer).

```
f[n_] := 2 Cos[n π/3]
Array[f, 100]
```