# Table mix with If function

Tags: list-manipulation, conditional

Anyone could explain to me which problem is? after running the function "Table" combining with "If" as below, but the result is not a value instead.

```
 k:=8; n:=k+1; Alpha:=Pi/6; r:=3;
 In[5]:= Subscript[y, n][i_] := r cos[i \[Alpha]]

 In[6]:= Subscript[y, n] = 
 Table[if [i == 1, Subscript[y, n][0], Subscript[y, n][i]], {i, 1, n}]

 Out[6]= {if[True, 3 cos[0], 3 cos[\[Pi]/6]], 
 if[False, 3 cos[0], 3 cos[\[Pi]/3]], 
 if[False, 3 cos[0], 3 cos[\[Pi]/2]], 
 if[False, 3 cos[0], 3 cos[(2 \[Pi])/3]], 
 if[False, 3 cos[0], 3 cos[(5 \[Pi])/6]], 
 if[False, 3 cos[0], 3 cos[\[Pi]]], 
 if[False, 3 cos[0], 3 cos[(7 \[Pi])/6]], 
 if[False, 3 cos[0], 3 cos[(4 \[Pi])/3]], 
 if[False, 3 cos[0], 3 cos[(3 \[Pi])/2]]}
```

Comment: Try If[] instead of if [] all MM functions start with Capitals

Comment: #Lou, thank you so much. My basic fault :(

Comment: Note also that the cosine function is `Cos` and the imaginary unit is `I`. When you define constants, you don't need to use `SetDelayed` (`:=`); use `Set` (`=`) instead (see [this FAQ](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18487/27951)).

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. The introductory [book](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/) written by the inventor is a good learning resource. There is a [fast intro for math students](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-math-students/en/) as well as a [fast intro for programmers](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/) to choose from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want something like the following:

```
Subscript[y, n][i_] := r Cos[i α] /. {r -> 3, α -> π/6}
Table[If[i == 1, Subscript[y, n][0], Subscript[y, n][i]], {i, 1, 9}]
(*{3, 3/2, 0, -(3/2), -((3 Sqrt[3])/2), -3, -((3 Sqrt[3])/2), -(3/2), 0}*)
```

Or in the same way:

```
Module[{s}, With[{k = 8}, s = k + 1; Table[If[i == 1, Subscript[y, n][0], Subscript[y, n][i]], {i, 1, s}]]]
(*{3, 3/2, 0, -(3/2), -((3 Sqrt[3])/2), -3, -((3 Sqrt[3])/2), -(3/2), 0}*)
```